# Where are avgRequestsPerSecond and avgTimePerRequest metrics in solr 7,8

Tags: solr

I am coding golang solr exporter which format the same with java solr-exporter of Apache Solr (it ate much RAM) . I want to add more metric like "avgTimePerRequest", "avgRequestsPerSecond".
According to [Solr document](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_3/performance-statistics-reference.html), it said that can query "avgTimePerRequest" and "avgRequestsPerSecond" via

```
"http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/metrics?group=core&prefix=UPDATE./update.requestTimes"

"http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/metrics?group=core&prefix=QUERY./select.requestTimes"
```

But when i couldn't see avgTimePerRequest or avgRequestsPerSecond, It only includes these

```
    "count":0,
    "meanRate":0.0,
    "1minRate":0.0,
    "5minRate":0.0,
    "15minRate":0.0,
    "min_ms":0.0,
    "max_ms":0.0,
    "mean_ms":0.0,
    "median_ms":0.0,
    "stddev_ms":0.0,
    "p75_ms":0.0,
    "p95_ms":0.0,
    "p99_ms":0.0,
    "p999_ms":0.0
```

With Solr 6, I can found "avgTimePerRequest" and "avgRequestsPerSecond" in mbean. But solr7,8 I couldn't found it? Does they need to enable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From SOLR v7.3 Change.txt
SOLR-8785: Metrics related classes in org.apache.solr.util.stats have been removed in favor of
  the dropwizard metrics library. Any custom plugins using these classes should be changed to use
  the equivalent classes from the metrics library.
  As part of this, the following changes were made to the output of Overseer Status API:
  * The "totalTime" metric has been removed because it is no longer supported
  * The metrics "75thPctlRequestTime", "95thPctlRequestTime", "99thPctlRequestTime"and "999thPctlRequestTime" in Overseer Status API have been renamed to "75thPcRequestTime", "95thPcRequestTime"
    and so on for consistency with stats output in other parts of Solr.

- **The metrics "avgRequestsPerMinute", "5minRateRequestsPerMinute" and "15minRateRequestsPerMinute" have been replaced by corresponding per-second rates viz. "avgRequestsPerSecond", "5minRateRequestsPerSecond" and "15minRateRequestsPerSecond" for consistency with stats output in other parts of Solr.**